# SQL Server Mgmt Studio-random assign data to new column from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble with a class assignment and I've gone thru various iterations.

**The assignment is:** "Randomly assign a serial number of a bat to each player by populating the new column you created in the AFFILIATION table. Make sure you abide by the team number that is included in the BATS table (i.e., do not associate a bat’s serial number with a player whose team does not have that bat)."

The table info is: Affiliation table has playernum as a PK, Teamnum as a PK, years, battingavg and playerbat. Playerbat is the new column that was created referenced in the assignment and has no data.

- Bats table has serialnum as a PK, manuf and teamnum
- Team table has teamnum as a PK, teamname, city, manager
- Player table only has playernum as PK, playername, and age so you can’t relate it back to any other tables

The "randomly assign" portion of the assignemnt is related to the fact that a team has more than one bat serialnum in the bats table.  Also players can play for more than one team.

This is what my last iteration looked like.

```
UPDATE affiliation SET playerbat = (SELECT serialnum FROM bats WHERE bats.teamnum = affiliation.teamnum
```

I’m using SQL server management studio btw, and it returns more than 1 value which is not permitted… I'm just seriously lost at this point. This is the last assignment in a SQL intro class.

Comment: I think you're almost there. You need to pick a random bat, and your last iteration is picking every single bat for that team. Has your class taught windowing functions?

Comment: Arthur, thanks for your input.  No we did not go thru windowing functions....